# Apache, PHP, Eclipse and Ubuntu 15.04 configuration troubles

Tags: server, permissions, eclipse

I am new to Ubuntu and PHP. I have a problem when I am trying to run some code.

I have this error: `The requested URL /helloworld.php was not found on this server.`. Everything should work, apache, php even phpmyadmin.

Also when I'm trying to create a project in the root folder, where apache is, it does not give me permission.

I hope you can understand me and help me to solve that problem.

Comment: Are you following some sort of tutorial? Could please Click "Edit" bellow your question and add the location of this tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

The second issue is because you do not have rights to write in the root folder.
To give yourself permission, open a terminal (ctrl+alt+t) and enter:

```
whoami
```

it will show your username, then navigate to the parent folder of your projects folder(if /home/projects then /home), and type

```
sudo chown <yourusername> <directoryname>
```

Comment: Should I do that every time when I want to create or open a project ?

Comment: @maDFrog no, just once, this way you change the owner of that directory to your normal user

Comment: One more stupid question, how to navigate to the folder? I tried
'cd  /home/workspace/'
but there is now such a directory according to the terminal ? Any ideas

Comment: normally it should be /home/<username>/workspace, but you shouls check in eclipse (right click to projects, properties and there is a Location...)